# Routing for sub ressources in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

So this is in routes file :

```
  resources :users do
    resources :lamps
  end
```

I want to be able to display a user's "lamps" with something like :

```
http://localhost:3000/users/2/lamps
```

and show all the existing lamps whichever user owns it using :

```
http://localhost:3000/lamps
```

both are very different as the first one is more of a management view and the later is more what a user browsing would see.

The thing is they both go to the index action of the lamp_controller

How can I manage this in a clean way without having to use if statements in my action/view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `module` option to route the nested routes to a namespaced controller:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
     resources :lamps, only: [:index], module: 'users' 
  end
  resources :lamps, only: [:index]
end
```

Another way to do this for a group of resources is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
     scope module: 'users'  do
       resources :lamps, only: [:index]
       resources :chairs
       resources :rugs
     end
  end
  resources :lamps, only: [:index]
end
```

This would let you handle the different contexts in separate controllers:

```
# app/controllers/lamps_controller.rb
class LampsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /lamps
  def index
    @lamps = Lamp.all
  end
end

# app/controllers/users/lamps_controller.rb
class Users::LampsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user

  # GET /users/:user_id/lamps
  def index
    @lamps = @user.lamps
    # renders /views/users/lamps/index.html.erb
  end

  private
     def set_user
       @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. the second option works perfectly. Ruby always has elegant solutions!

Comment: In the first example, how would you write the controllers so that the REST index service points of users/ and users/:id/lamps/ map to seperate controller actions?

Comment: @JulienLamarche I'm not sure what you mean. It would probably be better if you asked it as a separate question.